# Chromedriver: How to disable PDF plugin

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

To mimic functionality of how my Firefox profile is set up, I need to ensure that the PDF viewer for Chrome is disabled. after searching across the internet, the closest answer I find is here

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=528436

However attempting any of the suggestions on this page have given me no success

Here is a snippet of code I expect to work

```
                Dictionary<String, Object> plugin = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
                plugin.Add("enabled", false );
                plugin.Add("name", "Chrome PDF Viewer");
                var options = new ChromeOptions();
                options.AddUserProfilePreference("plugins.plugins_list", plugin);                   

                driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Can anyone see what exactly I am doing wrong? this is starting to become a really frustrating issue!

Comment: are you attempting to interact with the PDF using Selenium?

Comment: When the plugin is disabled, clicking on a link to a PDF will cause it to be downloaded to the default directory. This is why I need to find a way to disable the chrome PDF viewer plugin on startup

Comment: You can just disable the Chrome PDF Viewer by accessing chrome://plugins/ in the address bar.

Comment: I will try doing this on test startup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this works for *Selenium.WebDriver 2.53m, ChromeDriver 2.25.426923, and Chrome v55.0.2883.87 m*.

```
    var options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.AddUserProfilePreference("plugins.plugins_disabled", new []{"Chrome PDF Viewer"});
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 3):

For Chrome 57, I had to use this line instead:

```
options.AddUserProfilePreference("plugins.always_open_pdf_externally", true);
```

Additionally, if you ever need to set a plugin yourself you can find it like this:

1. Navigate to chrome://settings/content (Menu > Settings, Show advanced settings..., Content settings...).
2. Locate the specific preference (checkboxes only).
3. Right-click and Inspect the checkbox.
4. The preference name is the entire 'pref' attribute's value.

Answer (score -2):

This work for me (if the first link is **Chrome PDF Viewer** )

```
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("chrome://plugins/");
        Thread.Sleep(4000);
        driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Disable")).Click();
```